# Container with findNthSmallest in O(1)

Tags: data-structures

> Consider the following problem: we want to implement ADT SpecialContainer which stores integer numbers and is similar to a PriorityQueue. This container should support the following operations:
>
> - `init(sc, n)` - create a new, empty SpecialContainer `sc`. `n` is a positive integer number (will be used later) - $\Theta(1)$ total complexity
> - `push(sc, x)` - adds the integer number `x` to the SpecialContainer - $O(\log n)$ total complexity
> - `findNthSmallest(sc)` - returns the `n`th smallest element from `sc`, where `n` is the number given to the init function - $\Theta(1)$ total complexity
> - `popNthSmallest(sc)` - removes and returns the `n`th smallest element from sc - $O(\log n)$ total complexity
>
> 1. Which data structure or combination of data structures would you use as representation for the SpecialContainer and how?
> 2. Explain in short how would you implement each operation of the SpecialContainer and why the implementation fits the complexity requirement.

I was thinking about a combination of a heap and a hash map, but I don't think if it works. Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER**SCIENCE** @SE. There seems to be a parameter `n` missing from `find`/`popNthSmallest(sc)`.

Comment: What's the context where you encountered this task? Please credit the source of all copied material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by orlp, it's impossible to do in $O(\log n)$ time. However, we can do this in $O(\log N)$ time, where $N$ is the total number of items.

You can do this with 2 Heaps:
The first heap is a max-heap with the smallest $n$ elements. Its root is the $n$-th smallest element.
The second one is the min-heap with the rest of the elements. Its root is the $n+1$-th smallest element.

When max-heap has less than $n$ elements, the operations are trivial. Otherwise:

- findNthSmallest() - it's just the root of the max-heap. O(1) time
- popNthSmallest():

  1. Pop the root of the max-heap
  2. x := Pop the root of the min-heap
  3. Insert x into the max-heap
- push(x):

  1. Push x into the max-heap
  2. y := Pop the root of the max-heap.
  3. Push y into the min-heap.

Comment: This doesn't quite work because the operations on the min-heap will have $O(\log k)$ where $k$ is the total number of elements. That said, OP's original bounds are impossible (you could get linear time sorting simply by setting $n = 1$), so I think this solution is valid anyway.

Comment: @orlp, heap requires $O(\log n)$ for push/pop and $O(1)$ for peek (and findNthSmallest requires only peek), so, as far as I can tell, it matches the required complexity.

Comment: To make things unambiguous, a heap requires $O(\log s)$ for pop, where $s$ is the size of the heap. In `popNthSmallest`, which must have complexity $O(\log n)$ according to OP you call pop twice. Once on a heap with size $n$, so that is fine, but another time on a heap with size $k - n$, where $k$ is the total number of elements. That is not fine. Imagine if $k = 10^9$ and $n = 10$. The OP would expect $O(\log 10)$ but gets $O(\log (10^9 - 10))$ instead (abusing big O notation a bit).

Comment: @orlp, Ah, I see. I confused $n$'s.

Comment: If $n=2$ and you do `push(3)`,`push(2)`,`push(1)`, in that order, we have $3,2,1$ in the max-heap. If we do `findNthSmallest()` it will return `3`.

Comment: @plop, thanks, fixed.